# How can I update this function in plsql?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

this function check if all employees have their salary between the correct range of maximum and minimum salary. I want to update it so it would return the employees' ids whose salary is out of range ??
I tried and define a collection but it keeps giving me error . Any Ideas ??

```
create or replace function min_max return number as
cursor job_cur is
    select job_id, min_salary, max_salary from jobs;
cursor emp_cur(p_job_id jobs.job_id%type) is
    select employee_id, salary from employees where job_id = p_job_id;
Type id_table is table of number index by binary_integer;
return_id id_table;
i number := 1;
begin
for job_rec in job_cur loop
    for emp_rec in emp_cur(job_rec.job_id) loop
        if (emp_rec.salary > job_rec.max_salary)
            or (emp_rec.salary < job_rec.min_salary) then
            --return 0;
            return_id(i).emlpoyee_id := emp_rec.employee_id; // error here
            i := i+1;
        end if;
    end loop;
end loop;
--return 1;
return return_id;  // error here
end min_max;
```

Here is the updated code but it's not working . The errors :
Error(15,17): PL/SQL: Statement ignored.
Error(15,30): PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'NUMBER'.
Error(21,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored.
Error(21,12): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type.

Comment: can you add comments to the line where the error actually occurs?  it is hard to follow the block.

Comment: If you want to returns id(s) -- more than one --  that means you need to return a refcursor to an open resultset.  Not a number.

Comment: Or you could define a collection type and return that.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the type outside the function, the function can return a collection. Also, do not loop over two cursors. Always do SQL operations as a set if you can. You get vastly better performance that way.

This works, as long as the number of employees is not too large:

```
CREATE TYPE id_table AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION min_max RETURN id_table AS
  l_emp_list id_table;
BEGIN
  SELECT e.employee_id 
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_emp_list
    FROM employees e 
   INNER JOIN jobs j ON j.job_id = e.job_id
   WHERE e.salary NOT BETWEEN j.min_salary AND j.max_salary;

  RETURN l_emp_list;
END;
```

For some reason SQLFiddle is giving me an error, but this works in my database.

Comment: It means the database returns batches of results rather than row-by-row. Oracle is heavily optimized to operate on sets rather than individual rows. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/12_tune.htm#i48876